# Entity Framework SQLQuery Oracle specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I'm trying to retrieve list of `DbResult` from an oracle database table, with the code below by Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework 6.

```
var query = repository.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbResult>("SELECT NAME as Name,SUB_PORTFOLIO_INSTANCE_ID as SubPortfolioInstanceID,STATUS as Status FROM DGARSMART.T_SC_SERVICE");
List<DbResult> serviceList = query.ToList();
```

This query throws an exception:

> Specified method is not supported.

I think It's because of query trying to parse `STATUS` column(type of number(1,0) in Oracle) to bool Status property belongs to `DbResult`. How can I achieve parse that query to my `DbResult` class?

By the way if I remove `STATUS` statement from query it retrives data and parse to `DbResult` object successfully.

```
class DbResult
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   
   public DateTime SubPortfolioInstanceID { get; set; }

   public bool Status { get; set; }

 }
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetBoolean(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.ReadBool(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initialize(DbDataReader reader, DbSpatialDataReader spatialDataReader, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initialize(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, DbDataReader reader, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataReader.Initialize(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass24`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__23()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass24`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__22()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClasse`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__d()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
```

I'm using these packages:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.2.1100" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="12.2.20190115" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233237/mapping-boolean-property-to-oracle-using-entity-framework - There is an answer on here with a suggestion about modifying mapping in the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty solution is to use a hidden `Int32` property and expose it as a `Boolean` value.

See [mapping private property entity framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619955/mapping-private-property-entity-framework-code-first) and [Entity Framework Many to many through containing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807406/entity-framework-many-to-many-through-containing-object/13810766#13810766)

```
class DbResult
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public DateTime SubPortfolioInstanceID { get; set; }

   [Column("Status")]
   private Int32 HiddenStatus { get; set; }

   public Boolean Status => this.HiddenStatus != 0;

 }
```