# Oracleboolean data type mapping in EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I am generating edmx file by pointing Oracle database.By default it maps number(1,0) in oracle to Short data type. I searched and find to add one entry in app.config file/web config file.
like this:

```
 <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)" />
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

But in my case problem is that all projects in my solution are of class library type with no appconfig file and main startup project is of plugin type. So i am confused,where i can add this entry.Because when i manually add one appconfig file in class library(i know there is no use) it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10903313/38368

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF EDM Builder Oracle Number(1, 0) -> Int16/Bool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901237/ef-edm-builder-oracle-number1-0-int16-bool)

Comment: @Danny Varod..thanks for reply.Before posting my question i already gone through all similar questions. If i am understanding you correctly then you are talking about adding entry in Appconfig file. but the problem is that i dont have any webconfig or appconfig because all my projects are of class library type .I dont want to modify machine confile file. Do we have any other way to implement other than adding in Appconfig file ?

Comment: Either modify the client/host's app.config (or web.config if it is a web service) or the machine config. If you look at the link to the Oracle forum in that answer you'll see I asked Oracle this question already and they didn't take such scenarios into account: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2341638?tstart=0