# Oracle Data-Type Conversion in EF Core

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are migrating current VB.NET application into .NET CORE. Database is Oracle - Version: 12.

Previously we used ODP.NET to connect with Database, but now we are exploring other ORMs like Entity Framework Core 6.

When I execute command to generate POCO classes and ModelContext. it is taking incorrect Oracle Datatype into C# DataType.

Eg: INTEGER(1,0) --> Bool

Now when I execute LINQ query, it is giving Type Cast error.

Question is, how to resolve this DataType mismatch issues. We have hundreds of tables and hundreds of columns having INTEGER(1,0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF EDM Builder Oracle Number(1, 0) -> Int16/Bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901237/ef-edm-builder-oracle-number1-0-int16-bool)

Comment: We don't have EDMX file in EF Core. and also, we don't have app.config file in .NET CORE 6 API project.