# Can we use Code first approach migration with oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I am using mvc4 and Entity framework-5.

I wanted to implement Code first approach migration with oracle.

If yes please suggest what is the basic step need to follow.

Please don't suggest below url. i have followed "B" step and getting "No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'"

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721025/deploying-and-configuring-odp-net-to-work-without-installation-with-entity-frame
```