# How to map properly Oracle Number(1, 0) to boolean using Entity Framework?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, boolean

I am trying to use an Oracle number(1) in C# code using EF6 in DB-first mode. From what I could see, the only way to use such a type is by using a Boolean while mapping the entities in the edmx file, which is fine.
While the program is able to compile and to run, I always get the following error message when I am in designer mode in the edmx file:

`Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Boolean[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' [...] is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=1,Scale=0]'`

How can I get rid of this message while still mapping a boolean?

I am well aware that the Boolean type isn't supported in Oracle Databases. Each of the posts I saw suggested the mapping trick either manually or automatically by customizing the edmMappings in the app.config. Both of these solutions led to the above error message.
I tried with different entity types, none have worked. As this is a common issue, I suppose I missed something...

In this old SO ([Mapping .NET Boolean datatype to oracle number(1,0) in entity framework throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095695/mapping-net-boolean-datatype-to-oracle-number1-0-in-entity-framework-throws-e)), someone said there is nothing much to do about this message. Maybe there are news about this since then?